# select query from two different table with matching id

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have product table as

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

for each product, i have separate product type table, for Product_A_Type, i have type table as below

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | dcf |

like wise i have Product_B_Type table

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 |

and having stock table as

| id | product_id | product_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |

i am doing filter based on product and type combination for eg:-

in my select query, i will search with product as "A" and type as %ab%, in this case i need to get results based on product type A only, if i search with product "B" and type as %12% then the query should return results for product "B" and it should ignore product A. i tried with below query, but it returns empty row..

```
    select 
  * 
from 
  daily_stock 
where 
  (
    product_id in (
      select 
        id 
      from 
        products p 
      where 
        lower(p.name) like lower('%lubr%')
    ) 
    and product_type_id in (
      select 
        id 
      from 
        lubricant_type l 
      where 
        lower(l.type) like lower('%%')
    ) 
    and product_type_id in (
      select 
        id 
      from 
        lubricant_type l 
      where 
        lower(l.name) like lower('%%')
    )
  ) 
  and (
    product_id in (
      select 
        id 
      from 
        products p 
      where 
        lower(p.name) like lower('%lubr%')
    ) 
    and product_type_id in (
      select 
        id 
      from 
        fuel_type f 
      where 
        lower(f.type) like lower('%%')
    ) 
    and product_type_id in (
      select 
        id 
      from 
        fuel_type f 
      where 
        lower(f.name) like lower('%%')
    )
  )
```

edit
if i search for product "A" and type as "%ab%"

| id | product_id | product_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

for product "B" and type as "%12%", then result should be as..

| id | product_id | product_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output ?

Comment: @SelVazi added expected o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this query :

```
select ds.id, ds.product_id, ds.product_type_id
from daily_stock ds
inner join product p on p.id = ds.product_id
inner join Product_A_Type pa on pa.id = ds.product_type_id
inner join Product_B_Type pb on pb.id = ds.product_type_id
where p.name = 'A' and ( pa.type like '%ab%' or pb.type like '%ab%' )
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/js1ePs-M)

Comment: i have tested the query on postgresql,, but it is working partially, working on product b only, and product a is not working. only if i remove product b, then only product a is working

Comment: Can you provide more information? Perhaps you could update this fiddle with some simple data that you've tested and then share the link here?  https://dbfiddle.uk/js1ePs-M

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/jIxNDdvO, the last query with like %56% should return two rows. but it is returning only  one..  in my pgadmin, this is even not working..

Comment: the `daily_stock` table doesn't contains a row with `product_type_id` = (3, '356'), this is way we get only one record for type `B` !

Comment: select ds.id, ds.product_id, ds.product_type_id 
from daily_stock ds
inner join products p on p.id = ds.product_id
inner join lubricant_type pa on pa.id = ds.product_type_id
where p.name like '%LUBRICANT%' and ( pa.type like '%ACID%'  ) and ds.daily_sale_date_id = 123 is giving a record, but when i add "inner join fuel_type pb on pb.id = ds.product_type_id", the query is not giving any results. it is working fine in fiddle.. but not in pgadmin..